# ckeditor 4.7.0: Cannot read property 'checkReadOnly' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I recently updated from 4.6.0 to 4.7.0 and now I got this error:

Cannot read property 'checkReadOnly' of undefined
at f.insertElementIntoRange (/ckeditor470/ckeditor.js:363)

with 4.6.0, everything worked fine.

the code :

```js
var HTMLTextField = "<img ...>"
var element = window.opener.CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( HTMLTextField );

var oEditor   = window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances[window.opener.current_ed];

oEditor.insertElement(element);
```

the error occurs on oEditor.insertElement(element);

any ideas?

best regards

Bernd

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why this happened, but in my case issue disappeared after removing inline attribute from widget definition.

Comment: Can you explain this enough so that it's useful for others?